# Laravel recursion - calling itself in a class

Tags: php, laravel, recursion

My current code:

```
public function countThreads() {
    $count = $this->threads->count();
    if ($this->hasSubforum()) {
        foreach ($this->subforums as $subforum) {
            $count += $this->countThreads($subforum);
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

I am currently accessing the "thread" as `$this` inside my model. I need to pass in the `$subforum` to itself but how can I do that in a class?

In my controller, I'm simply doing:

```
$forum = Forum::where('id', $id)->first();
$forum->countThreads();
```

How can I do recursion with this? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass any arguments*, you can call the `countThreads` method on the subforum `$subforum->countThreads()`

```
public function countThreads() 
{
    $count = $this->threads->count();
    if ($this->hasSubforum()) {
        foreach ($this->subforums as $subforum) {
            $count += $subforum->countThreads();
        }
    }

    return $count;
}
```

---

If you *really want to* pass it in as an argument, the correct way would be to write it as a service outside of the model